# spring 3 security schema username as primary key?

Tags: primary-key, spring-security

I Googled for this, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere. Why does the Spring 3 Security schema (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-schema.html) have a username as a primary key instead of an integer guid?

People often suggest that using "natural" usernames as your pk is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is the default schema.  I think they tried to make it simple and understandable.  Most people using Spring Security do not use these default schemas but rather adapt Spring Security to their needs.

For instance these default schemas can be replaced with your own schema, then you need to extend JdbcDaoImpl to have different queries which will be called:

```
setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(...);
setGroupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(...);
setUsersByUsernameQuery(...);
```

These methods on JdbcDaoImpl change the queries it uses to interface with the security DB.

Grant